# How to retrieve most recent past date from current date and most future date from current date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a small application that records appointment visits of patients. I have a both a `Patient` table and `Appointment` table.

In Appointment table, I have the following fields: `AppointmentId`, `AppointmentDate`, `PatientId`

In Patient table, I have `PatientId`, `PatientName`

In the `Appointment` table I have records as follows:

```
1 | 2020-08-08 | 2
2 | 2020-10-11 | 2
3 | 2020-12-15 | 2
4 | 2020-12-24 | 2
```

What I want to retrieve is that for all patients, I fetch the datasets of the `PatientId`. I want to retrieve the last appointment date, i.e `2020-10-11` and next appointment date, i.e `2020-12-15` if I run the query today.

I have tried the following but no getting the desired results. Can anyone please help me with this SQL query?

```
SELECT 
    patient.PatientName,
    MAX(appointment.AppointmentDate) AS NextVisit,
    MIN(appointment.AppointmentDate) AS LastVisit
FROM 
    Patient patient 
INNER JOIN 
    Appointment appointment ON patient.PatientId = appointment.PatientId
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, etc.) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `left joins` in sql as follows:

```
Select p.patientid, patientname,
       Max(ap.appointmentdate) as previous_appointment,
       Min(an.appointmentdate) as next _appointment
  from patient p
  Left join appointment ap on p.patientid = ap.patientid and ap.appointmentdate < sysdate
  Left join appointment an on p.patientid = an.patientid and an.appointmentdate > sysdate
Group by p.patientid, p.patientname
```

You can also use the `conditional aggregation` as follows:

```
Select p.patientid, patientname,
           Max(case when ap.appointmentdate < sysdate then ap.appointmentdate end) as previous_appointment,
           Min(case when ap.appointmentdate > sysdate then ap.appointmentdate end) as next _appointment
  from patient p
       Left join appointment ap on p.patientid = ap.patientid
Group by p.patientid, p.patientname
```

Please use `>=` or `<=` instead of `<` and `>` in condition according to your requirement.